# How are these definitions of continuous relations equivalent?

Tags: continuity, definition, relations

Here are two different definition of the "continuity of preference relations" (perhaps the definition of continuity of any type of relation is the same?)

> [image]
>
> [image]

**My question is: I don't see how these definitions are equivalent.**

Comment: I see one definition and one axiom. Maybe the axiom is not meant as equivalent to the definition. Also there is a single "twiddle" in the axiom, but the partial order symbol for the preference relation, which might not be related.

Comment: @coffeemath, the second source later states as an axiom. that the preference relation is continuous (as defined in 6.B.3.). And the sources are on exactly the same theorem, namely the expected utility theorem of von Neuman Morgenstern preferences.